# How to Playback Multiple Audio Files Starting at Different Times

Tags: audio, vlc

I have two audio files of different durations.  I want to play them simultaneously with the shorter duration starting in the middle of the longer duration file.

I've enabled media synchronization with the app launch setting `--sout-all --sout #display`.

Swapping between input-master and -slave settings results in either the shorter file not playing or nothing played back.

How can this be done in VLC?

Answer (score 0):

As of the date of this response, asynchronized audio playback or recordings where files start and end at different times cannot be done using a single instance of VLC alone without customized addons, if available.  This case is not an intended use of the VLC standard application.

It is possible yet cumbersome to have asynchronized playback with two or more instances of VLC and manually starting and ending each audio track.

**ALTERNATIVES**

Alternatively, there are numerous online audio editing tools, many accessible freely, that permit uploading audio files as separate tracks for playback, editing, mixing, or recording and for downloading that are much more advanced than the features of an uncustomized VLC.

A web search for "audio editors online" will produce a lengthy list of options.